# Chrome DevTools Memory Inconsistency

Tags: javascript, memory, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a game using JavaScript that runs at 60 FPS and have noticed a large amount of garbage collection happening (7.2 MB every 1.5 seconds, see below Chrome DevTools), which has a noticeable impact on frame rate.

[image: performance tab]

I've used the Allocation Timeline to see what is being added to memory every frame. As you can see below, there is 4.1 kB allocated every frame. So I would expect to see 369 kB garbage collected every 1.5 seconds.

[image: memory tab]

Why is there an order of magnitude difference between the two? I've been using the Allocation Timeline to reduce the memory used (it was originally 18 kB every frame). However this has had almost zero impact when looking at the Performance tab.

Is there are any way to know what is being garbage collected, as the Allocation Timeline doesn't seem to be correct?

#### Additional Info

- Here's a Heap Snapshot comparison between two moments in the game. This also doesn't seem consistent, and it includes lots of things which I would not expect to have changed every frame.

[image: heap snapshot]

- I tried removing the amount of objects (in an array) in my game **and this did make a big impact** in the Performance tab. But I really want to see this array listed somewhere in the DevTools so I can work on optimising it.
- I tried disabling rendering on the screen, but this didn't have an impact. So the GC is from game code.
- Measuring in Safari shows similar results to Chrome's performance tab.

[image: safari]

Comment: do you use `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: Yes, in fact I am using the Replay engine if you're curious to see the source: https://github.com/edbentley/replay

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a way around this: I removed the loop in the engine and have each frame run when a key is pressed.

This way I can take a heap snapshot, progress just one frame, then quickly take another snapshot (before GC kicks in). The "Objects allocated between snapshot" view seems to be more consistent, and shows a lot of memory used up by the JS engine's internal data like function scope.

[image]