# Chrome (system) function_data memory usage every frame

Tags: javascript, memory, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I have a game loop which is using over 100 kB memory / frame at 60 FPS, and so causing many garbage collections, which can impact the frame rate.

I'm comparing memory snapshots between frames in Chrome (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66567771)) and am seeing a high amount of `function_data` created and cleaned up every frame.

For example in the screenshot below, I have a `run` function (that lives in its own file, so there's no closure except for static imports) that has a high `function_data` memory footprint every frame.

[image: devtools]

Is there any way to either reduce the size of `function_data`, or ideally, not have it removed and recalculated in memory every frame? The function is quite long and has lots of properties in its object argument and is nested within lots of other functions when called. But that's hard to avoid since it's the core game loop.

Comment: Looks like your code creates new function(s) or closures thereof.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think you're right! I didn't realise that was the cause before. I commented out most of the code in `run` to test it out, and it went down to 1 kB retained size. I'll see if I can optimise the memory usage from there.